# Solve the following initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following initial initial value problem

$x dy + (y-y^2\ln(x))dx = 0,   y(1) = 1/4$

So far i've approached it by trying to separate it and get

$dx/x = dy/(y-y^2\ln(x))$

When I go to the the integral with respect to y for the left side i'm unsure what to do for the $\ln(x)$ term.

So I tried to approach it as an exact type of problem instead and get that its not exact, but when I put it into the form $(diM/diY - diN/diX)/N$ I get $2y\ln(x)/x$.

Im not sure how to do symbol for partial derivative so I said $di$ instead.

Is that my integrating factor? It isn't in terms of only x so i'm confused.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As LutzL answered, using $y=\frac 1 z$ the equation becomes
$$-\frac{x z'-z+\log (x)}{z^2}=0$$ So, consider
$$x z'-z=-\log (x)$$ The homogeneous is simple
$$xz'-z=0\implies z=C x$$ Now, if you prefer variation of parameters instead of integrating factor, then
$$x^2 C'=-\log (x) \implies C'=-\frac {\log(x)} {x^2}$$ and $C$ is easily obtained using integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

As equation for $y$ it is also Bernoulli. Which means that replacing $y=z^{-1}$, $dy=-z^{-2}dz$ gives
$$
-xdz+(z-\ln x)dx=0.
$$
Now that the equation is linear in $z$ the integrating factor is obvious as $x^{-2}$ where then
$$
-d((xy)^{-1})-x^{-2}\ln(x)dx=0
$$
is exact.